# SQL Constraints Exception - Xamarin Mobile app IOS

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin.ios

i have an issue which is driving me up the wall.

The code below adds a note into the database which is then listed out.  The problem is, it adds the first note perfectly fine, then i go to add another note and i get a "Constraints" error!   I just can see why.

### Modal;

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    [Table("notes")]
    public class Note
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Unique]
        public long ProgramId { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }


        public static void addNote(Note newNote)
        {

            //SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(AssessNETApp.Data.Globals.DB);
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(AssessNETApp.Data.Globals.DB))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Insert(newNote);
                }
                catch (SQLiteException ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                }
            }
        }
```

---

### Code for button click to add note

```
async void OnAddNoteButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Text.Text.Length > 0)
        { 

            Note NoteData = new Note();
            NoteData.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            NoteData.TaskId = thisTask.TaskId;
            NoteData.UserId = MyApp.Data.LoggedInUser.UserID;
            NoteData.Content = Text.Text.ToString();

            Note.addNote(NoteData);

            await Navigation.PopAsync();
         }
 }
```

---

First note i add , fine!  Second, error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Unique]
public long ProgramId { get; set; }
```

if you don't explicitly assign a ProgramID, it will default to 0.  So the first is Unique, but the second is also 0, which violates the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I have since fixed it.  For some reason i wondered if the actual data table had been altered considering they remain on the device.   I have now dropped the tables so they re-create and hence this has actually removed where i did have [Unique].

Lesson learnt is that if you make changes to the Model, drop the tables else its still just running off the original unless the DB or tables are created each time you use the app.